# Multiple SFDC Users on one PC

Tags: login

We are implementing Live Agent, and I am trying to simulate testing 20 or so live agents online at the same time.  To do this, I need to setup 20 different users.  From what I can see, the only options I have for this is to either use a different browser for each user - which is limited to the number of different browsers I have installed on my PC - or to use Chrome in incognito mode, which seems to limit me to one extra user.  So the question is, is there any other way to have 20 different users logged into one PC at the same time?

Comment: For quite a few $ you can run multiple browser instances at e.g. https://www.browserstack.com/pricing.

Comment: This isn't really a salesforce question at this point, but one suggestion would be to go in to Users on your computer, add a bunch of new User accounts, and then use Switch User to switch between users. Alternatively, get a VM server, and spin up 20 copies of Windows. Or, if you've got a really beefy system, install Microsoft Virtual PC, create 20 new copies of Windows, and go from there... Point is, there's no way you're going to just get 20 logins in the same org in a single OS user account.

Comment: Fox, does the SFDC session for a user stay online when you switch to another user?

Comment: @hamayoun Looks like there's some tricks I didn't know about, but to speak directly, yes, processes running on users other than the one you're currently logged in as still run. I'm not sure if a "normal" computer could handle 20 logins at once though, unless you had 16-32GB of installed memory or so. Try the browser extensions and see if those work for you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a question many Salesforce consultants will face - we will need to open many Salesforce instances and many of them are under the same domain.

I would recommend using some multi-session plugins for this purpose:

**multi-fox for firefox**: https://addons.mozilla.org/EN-us/firefox/addon/multifox-toolbar-button/?src=search

**Sessionbox for chrome**: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sessionbox-free-multi-log/megbklhjamjbcafknkgmokldgolkdfig?hl=en

**multi-login**: https://multiloginapp.com/

I haven't used them for quite a while now and I remember the last time I worked with SessionBox and multi-login I had some small issues - which are not show stoppers though. The last time I used multi-fox I didn't have much issue.

If anybody is interested in how those plugins work underneath, here is a simple explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519835/how-does-multi-login-extension-works

Comment: Multi-fox... what an awesome word pun!

Comment: @sfdcfox I added a link about in stackoverflow about how it works underneath. But I am not quite sure how much memory it will take though. In the maximum I have only opened up to 10 sessions in the past.

Comment: Multi-login was the best one, allowed me to test with upto 10 users.  Only caveat is that you need to use a supported browser version, and it does not seem to support the latest versions of Chrome/FF.  So I had to install an old version of FF, and then switch off auto update.  Thanks Lance!

Comment: for me, multiple browsers + private/incognito browsing, which doubles things (2 for safari, 2 for firefox, 2 for chrome), layering with the above solutions could multiply how many you get

Comment: Lance - the multifox link is broken

Comment: @cropredy Thank you for the reminder. I have updated the link.